# Finding an angle of a triangle

Tags: geometry

Suppose $ BD=AC=4$, $\angle ABC=50$, $\angle ACB=100$, and $\angle BCD=130$. Find degree of $\angle BDC$.

[image: adjacent_triangles]

For this I could not find the measure of the angle

Comment: Hint: You know all angles of triangle ABC. And you know one side length. So you know also all side lengths (including BC). You know then BC, BD and BCD angle... You should be able to get everything from there.

Comment: @Martigan : But how can find side lengths of $ABC$?

Comment: Use the Law of Sines.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig : My dear I do not know any thing about this Law. It was not in my text book

Comment: Tom, the link to the image is broken. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't know thw law of sines , let me state it here as I will be using it:

> If $A,B,C$ are the angles of a triangle, and $a,b,c$ the respective opposite sides, then the law of sines states that $${a\over \sin(A)}={b\over \sin(B)}={c\over \sin(C)}$$

From triangle $ABC$ we have $\angle BAC=30^o$, so $BC=\frac{4\sin30^o}{\sin50^o}$.

From triangle $BCD$ we have $BC=\frac{4\sin BDC}{\sin130^o}$.

But $\sin130^o=\sin50^o$, so $\sin BDC=\sin30^o$. Obviously $\angle BDC<90^o$, so $\angle BDC=30^o$.

[Note that to prove the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) you just consider the altitudes. For example, the altitude from $C$ has length $BC\sin C$ and $CA\sin A$.]

Comment: Thanks for your attention. But I should find degree with the rules in my text book

Comment: @Tom you should edit your question telling what rules you can use.

Comment: Then you have failed to give critical information in the question. Please add the rules you are happy to use. Note that proving the sine law is a triviality (the proof is given above).

Answer (score 2):

Consider a trapezoid $BCD'A$ with $BD'=AC$ and $BA\parallel CD'$.
Since $BCD'A$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, $\widehat{CD'B}=\widehat{BAC}=30^\circ$. If we take $D$ as the symmetric of $D'$ with respect to the $BC$ line, the given constraints are fulfilled and

> $$ \widehat{BDC}=\widehat{BD'C}=\widehat{BAC}=\color{red}{30^\circ}.$$

[image]